# How to set values by default using Radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm using a `Map` to store the state of my component. Within this component, I have 3 groups, and in each group I have radio buttons. I have this array so that I can set values by default:

```
const defaultOptions = [
    { label: "Mark", value: "mark" },
    { label: "Steve", value: "steve" },
    { label: "Paul", value: "Paul" }
  ];
```

How can I set values by default using this array?

Here's live [**DEMO**](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-helloworld-forked-j3kwkd?file=/src/components/Post.tsx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the `Map` based on the array of defaults like so:

```js
// in the App component
useEffect(() => {
    const newPosts = someJson;
    setPosts(newPosts);
    setSearchResults(newPosts);
    setCheckboxStates(
      new Map(defaultOptions.map(o => 
        [newPosts.find(p => p.fields.some(f => f.name === o.label)).label, [o]]))
    );
}, []);
```

Comment: [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-helloworld-forked-kq6y87?file=/src/App.tsx)

Answer (score -1):

you must use the `checked`prop

```
    <article>
      {showGroup && (
        <div>
          {post.fields?.map((field: any, idx: number) => {
            const itemsSelected = checkboxStates
            .get(post.label)
            ?.some((o) => o.label === field.name)
            const isChecked =
              itemsSelected !== null || itemsSelected !== undefined ? itemsSelected : defaultOptions.some(item => item.value === field.value);
            return (
              <div key={idx}>
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  name={post.label}
                  value={field.value}
                  checked={isChecked}
                  onChange={(e) =>
                    handleRadiobuttonChange(field, e.target.checked)
                  }
                />
                <span>{field?.name}</span>
                <br />
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      )}
    </article>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Can you provide a working live demo, please?